# SonarQube 3.5.1 - how to exclude directory from analysis

Tags: sonarqube

I have my project code structure  something like

```
 module1
     submodule1
     submodule2
 module2
     submodule1
     submodule2
 module3
     submodule1
     submodule2

 pom.xml
```

If I want to exlude the full directory module1 from sonar analysis, how to do that?

I tried multiple options like skiModules, exlusions, could not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the best option is to define a profile (in your POM) in which you redefine the list of modules that you really want to analyse (so in your example, you won't list module1). Then, when running a SonarQube analysis, you have to activate this profile:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -PsonarQubeAnalysisProfile
```

Note that we should soon implement a feature that will allow you to set a property "sonar.skip" in the POM of the modules that you want to exclude in order to make all this simpler. Please watch and vote for the following JIRA ticket: [MSONAR-91](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSONAR-91)

Answer (score 0):

In your sonar-project.properties file add the following (to exclude multiple directories use comma separated folder paths)

```
sonar.exclusions=module1/**, module2/**
```

And while running the sonar runner I got the following in the log

```
Excluded sources: 
  module1/**
  module2/**
```